# componentWillReceiveProps not firing on router param change

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-router

I am using `react-router-redux` along with `redux`, `react-router` and `react` and have everything working quite well in this repo:

https://github.com/justsayno/redux-react-introduction-code/tree/issue-branch

(look in branch `issue-branch` for reproducting my issue)

I have integrated the `react-router` state into my redux state using `react-router-redux` and can successfully use mapStateToProps to get the router parameter `employeeId` I need from the props like so:

(The following is from [this file](https://github.com/justsayno/redux-react-introduction-code/blob/issue-branch/src/containers/EmployeeProfile.js))

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({ 
    employeeId : ownProps.params.employeeId,
    employee: state.selectedEmployee.item,
    hasLoaded: state.selectedEmployee.hasLoaded,
    hasError: state.selectedEmployee.hasError,
    error: state.selectedEmployee.error
})
```

In my render function I can `console.log(`The employeeId is ${this.props.employeeId}`)` and it changes as I route to that component and the params change.

But for reasons I do not understand this does not fire when the params change.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log(nextProps)
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is a differnet mock API call for the list of employees vs the single employee and I need to re-retrieve the employee when the employeeId param changes or else I only see one of the employees. I was going to do this in my `componentWillReceiveProps` function, check the employeeId for changes and kick off an action if it has like so:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    const { employeeId, selectEmployee } = this.props
    if(nextProps.employeeId !== employeeId){
        selectEmployee(nextProps.employeeId)
    }
}
```

Am I just approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`componentWillReceiveProps` fires only when props changes. In your case you have initial props with `employeeId` set and doesn't change. You can reach `employeeId` in `componentWillMount`.

And the problem with your [`selectEmployee` call](https://github.com/justsayno/redux-react-introduction-code/blob/issue-branch/src/store.js#L64) is that it doesn't dispatch `employeeSelected`, because `hasLoaded` is set once to `true` in `EMPLOYEE_RECEIVED` action and later never change, so `selectEmployee` returns before dispatching `employeeSelected`, which suppose to change `hasLoaded` back to false in `EMPLOYEE_SELECTED`.

Comment: You are right, I figured it out eventually that since the route was changing it was re-mounting... Idiot. Your solution is correct.